# Python = XML to table form in Excel using win32com

Tags: python, excel, xml, pycharm

When attempting to open my xml files, I am prompted with three choices:

"Please select how you would like to open this file:

1. As an XML table
2. As a read-only workbook
3. Use the XML Source task pane."

Option 1 basically opens the xml file in a table in an excel worksheet, which is beautiful and easy to work with. More importantly, I have done all of my data cleaning in R on this format.

Now, I would like to automate the process of simply opening the xml file, selecting open "as an XML table" and then saving as an xlsx file.

I am very close to doing this using win32com, but the issue is that the file seems to be saved in the "As a read-only workbook" mode which means all of the column headers are messed up.

**My Question:** I want to convert an XML file into a table like that feature in excel does it and then immediately save it into xlsx format (without even opening the xml file) using preferably win32com.

My current code:

```
excel = win32com.client.DispatchEx('Excel.Application')
# excel.visible = True
xml1 = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.getcwd() + "\\" + "1.xml")
xml1.SaveAs(os.getcwd() +"\\" + "1.xlsx")
xml1.Close()
```

I do not want to open every xml file, it is not very time efficient.

Comment: You can't convert until workbook is loaded with XML. You can keep process in background with `visible` property as `False`. Also, look into [`Workbook.OpenXML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.openxml) for needed format. Read on argument.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Your link to Workbook.OpenXML was incredibly useful. The option to open as a table vs workbook is here is here: xml1 = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.getcwd() + "\\" + "1.xml",1,2). The 2 specifies
that option while the default is 0 which indicates open in read only mode.